# Calculate time for each person to stays in the factory

Tags: excel, vba

There are dates in the cell and times of entering and leaving the factory. I want to calculate how many hours each person has stay in the day they come to the factory. For this, I wrote a macro like this and I defined each person as sicil_no , but since there are multiple entries and exits at different times on the same date, I need to determine the last and first exit times for each day and subtract them. I didnt figure out how to do the last part

Sub macro()

Dim sicil_no As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim end_row As Long
Dim dates As Range
Dim gecis_yonu As String
Dim entry As String
Dim Exits As String

```
end_row = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row


For i = 3 To end_row
sicil_no = Cells(i, 3).Value
dates = Cells(i, 1).Value

    If Range("J", i).Value = "Exit" Then
        Range("J", i).Value = exist
    End If
    
    If Range("J", i).Value = "Entry" Then
        Range("J", i).Value = entry
    End If
    


    Next

        For Each dates In Range("A", end_row)
        
        
        Range("M", i).Value = exist - entry
        
        
        
        Next
```

End Sub

Comment: If the in/out of workers in the factory is in the same day (before 0:00:00) you could use `MIN` and `MAX` to retrieve the lowest time value and the highest.

Comment: How should i do it? I need to do for each person on the list and for each date

Comment: Well, a screenshoot with an example would help... We are blind here...

Comment: I am new so i dont know how to post screenshot here but smt like this, I have 10 person on my list. I have record for every one of them to come to factory in different days. every day they enter 1 time and exit 1 time some days they enter and exit more than 2 times so there might records more than 2 for some days. I want to calculate for each person's spent time in factory at that day

Comment: nesrin you can edit your post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67261657/edit) and by pressing Ctrl+G you can upload images or directly paste them from your computer. We need to see the way your data is distributed along the sheet.

Comment: Thanks! I got it. Because the confiential I am not allowed to share original document but i put an example of it. there are 6000 data in real document

Comment: Last question, where do you intend to output the time worked for each day and worker if there can be more than one row for that?

Comment: when you see the image Burcu comes 08:08, leaves 17:30 at 23/04/2021 what i want to do to calculate 17:30 minus 08:08. and i want that calculations for everyday and every person

Comment: That I got it, but where do you want that time outputed? in the first row for each worker and day?

Comment: Yes! in the first row of each date

Comment: Could you find a way to figure out?

Comment: You can solve this issue with pivot tables. Probably no need for code.

Comment: Thank you so much guys! Andreas it was a very helpful explanation thank you so much

Comment: A modification is needed. I need to find total time stayed in factory and i need to consider all entry and exists. Do you know how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain your desired output using `Power Query`, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365 Excel

You did not show what you want for output, but you can add to what I have shown which is the bare minimum `Sicil`, `Date` and Time between earliest and latest times.  *(Assuming each pair of times is **entry/exit**, you could also sum the differences between each pair of times per day*)

In the Query, you can sort the results depending on whether you want to show by date or by employee.

- Select some cell in your original table
- `Data => Get&Transform => From Table/Range`
- When the PQ UI opens, navigate to `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table Name in Line 2 of the code.
- Replace the existing code with the **M-Code** below
- Change the table name in line 2 of the pasted code to your "real" table name
- Examine any comments, and also the `Applied Steps` window, to better understand the algorithm and steps

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],

//Add custom column with just the Date part for grouping
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Date", each Date.From([Dates])),

//Group by Sicil No and Date
//Then extract the time in Factory as the last time less the first time
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Custom", {"Sicil No", "Date"}, {
        {"Hrs in Factory", each List.Max([Dates]) - List.Min([Dates]), type duration}   
        }),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Grouped Rows",{{"Date", type date}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

[image]

***Edit***

If you want to add up the **actual** time in the factory per day, taking into account the entry/exit times:

- Assuming times are entered as pairs, where the first time is entry and the second is exit
- Merely subtract one from the other to get each duration
- The group as above and add the total durations per Sicil and Date

***M Code***

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],

//Add custom column with just the Date part for grouping
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Date", each Date.From([Dates])),

//Add Index column to access previous row
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Added Custom", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),

//if the Index number is an Odd number,
//   then subtract the previous row from the current row to get the Duration
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Duration", each 
        if Number.Mod([Index],2)=0
            then null 
            else [Dates]- Table.Column(#"Added Index","Dates"){[Index]-1}),

//Group by Sicil and Date
//  SUM the durations
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Custom1", {"Sicil No", "Date"}, {
        {"Time in Factory", each List.Sum([Duration]), type nullable duration}}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Grouped Rows",{{"Sicil No", Int64.Type}, {"Date", type date}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

[image]

***further modification to account for "real" list not being sorted as needed, and also data errors with mismatch of entry/exits
Also different routine to refer to previous row for speed improvements***

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],

//Change type especially datetime to Turkish culture (since I am in US)
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"GECIS TARIHI", type datetime}, {"KART NUMARASI", type any}, {"SICIL NUMARASI", Int64.Type}, {"SOYADI", type text}, 
        {"ADI", type text}, {"FİRMASI", type text}, {"GEÇİÇİ TAŞERON", type any}, {"BÖLÜM KODU", type any}, 
        {"TERMINAL", type any}, {"GEÇİŞ YÖNÜ", type text}, {"GEÇİŞ DURUMU", type any}, {"ZONE", type any}}, "tr-TR"),

//Remove columns that will not appear in final report
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type",{"KART NUMARASI", "SOYADI", "ADI", "FİRMASI", "GEÇİÇİ TAŞERON", 
            "BÖLÜM KODU", "TERMINAL", "GEÇİŞ DURUMU", "ZONE"}),

//Sort for proper processing
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Removed Columns",{{"SICIL NUMARASI", Order.Ascending}, {"GECIS TARIHI", Order.Ascending}}),

//add shifted columns to reference previous rows for entry/exit and time
//much faster than using the Index column method
    ShiftedList = {null} &  List.RemoveLastN(Table.Column(#"Sorted Rows", "GEÇİŞ YÖNÜ"),1),
    Custom1 = Table.ToColumns(#"Sorted Rows") & {ShiftedList},
    Custom2 = Table.FromColumns(Custom1, Table.ColumnNames(#"Sorted Rows") & {"GEÇİŞ YÖNÜ" & " Prev Row"}),

    ShiftedList1 = {null} &  List.RemoveLastN(Table.Column(Custom2, "GECIS TARIHI"),1),
    Custom3 = Table.ToColumns(Custom2) & {ShiftedList1},
    Custom4 = Table.FromColumns(Custom3, Table.ColumnNames(Custom2) & {"GECIS TARIHI" & " Prev Row"}),

//Calculate duration on the appropriate rows
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Custom4, "Time in Factory", each 
        if [GEÇİŞ YÖNÜ] = "Exit" and [GEÇİŞ YÖNÜ Prev Row] = "Entry"
            then [GECIS TARIHI] - [GECIS TARIHI Prev Row]
            else null),

//Filter out the unneeded rows
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each ([Time in Factory] <> null)),

//Remove the offset columns
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"GEÇİŞ YÖNÜ Prev Row", "GECIS TARIHI Prev Row"}),

//add Date column for grouping
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns1", "Date", each DateTime.Date([GECIS TARIHI]),Date.Type),

//Group by Date and Sicil and SUM the Time in Factdory
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Custom1", {"SICIL NUMARASI", "Date"}, {
        {"Time in Factory", each List.Sum([Time in Factory]), type duration}
        })
in
  #"Grouped Rows"
```

[image]

Comment: Hi again, i need some modifications on that solution, i need to do the same thing but i should consider all date times not just max and min. How should i edit m code? I should find the total hours stayed on that day and i need to calculate all of entry and exist hours

Comment: @nesrin  See my **Edit**

Comment: It doesnt work, do you know how to do it by using macro? by the way sicil no is a unique number to describe people like ID number.

Comment: @nesrin "doesn't work" is not useful information. If you want help with any solution, be specific. And yes, it could be done "using macro", but PQ is easier to write. From the data you provided, as you can see from the screen shot, it is returning the information you requested. So here it **DOES** work, but maybe I have misunderstood what you want. – Ron Rosenfeld

Comment: What i meant by it doesn't work, i couldn't do it by myself. I get on error about clock type i guess. I tried to add a picture but its not allowed it says. 0.00:37:19, 0.02:14:56  for example i get hours like it but those are not correct. I tried to change type by smt else but i broke completely, thats why i couldn't do. Maybe you can tell me which clock type you use and try that too. Thanks a lot

Comment: Data type is duration when i change it to 'Time' i see error written in cells. And Also, i saw that the calculation is wrong in some cells. For example when i see the PQ its seen as "null" but when i see the original document that person comes for 12 hours on that day. Thats another problem. I can share more information as image but its nor allowed for me because of the page's rules and limitations

Comment: @nesrin You shouldn't have to be changing data types in PQ. Probably your real data is different from your examples. Edit your question to post text example of data that causes error, or upload an xlsx workbook with data that doesn't work to some sharing site and post link here.

Comment: https://onedrive.live.com/edit.aspx?cid=0a935a4221b53e02&page=view&resid=A935A4221B53E02!137&parId=A935A4221B53E02!105&app=Excel      yes youre right i think the problem is the original data format. I copy a part of original document and share it here. Can you see it? if not i can send it to your mail or something else. Thank you so much

Comment: @nesrin Remove sensitive info and post the link.

Comment: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AgI-tSFCWpMKgQk3EjoOL5Mwr0Cv?e=zyZYEW @ron rosenfeld  Isn't it working?

Comment: @nesrin This link works. Af first glance, it seems the issue is that your actual data is not sorted the same way as your sample data. I'll take a closer look at the file.

Comment: okay thank you so much your doing a huge favour to me, i am really appreciate.

Comment: @nesrin In addition to the sorting issue, which you could easily fix in PQ by sorting by Sicil and date, you also have an inconsistency in the data.  `2312` has two consecutive `Entry`s, at `10 03 2021  07:08:57` and `10 03 2021  07:09:01` with no intervening `Exit`.  How would you handle that?

Comment: I just realize it you're right. maybe it can be done by if two entry exist consecutively picking the last one. By using macro what i thought was for each sicil, count every days entry and exit number, for example 2 entry and 2 exit exist for one person on a specific day, it wil count as entry-> 1  exist ->2  entry->3   exist-> 4 and to calculate time in factory 2-1 + 4-3    I guess you also did something like that

Comment: @nesrin Since your real data has Entry/Exit flags, I suggest changing the formula for the column that calculates Duration to: if [GEÇİŞ YÖNÜ]="Entry" then null else if [GEÇİŞ YÖNÜ] = "Exit" and Table.Column(#"Added Index","GEÇİŞ YÖNÜ"){[Index]-1} = "Entry" then [GECIS TARIHI]- Table.Column(#"Added Index","GECIS TARIHI"){[Index]-1} else null. Instead of checking the Index Number being odd/even, we check to the status of the current and/or previous row GEÇİŞ YÖNÜ. Other things should work out OK

Comment: @nesrin See my **edit** which includes this last code modification.  One other assumption: Do people ever stay in the factory past midnight?  In other words, could there be an entry on one day with no exit until the next?  Current algorithm will not account for that.

Comment: Expression.Error: The column 'Duration' of the table wasn't found.
Details:
    Duration

Comment: In normal circumstances no, but i am not sure if there will be exceptions

Comment: @nesrin You probably didn't name the column that calculates the duration properly. Check the step in the Applied Steps window to see which line that error first appears.

Comment: 1drv.ms/x/s!AgI-tSFCWpMKgQk3EjoOL5Mwr0Cv?e=zyZYEW could you check this again i add a picture

Comment: @nesrin I cannot tell anything about the source of error from the screenshot. It does not show the code, nor can I access the applied steps.  And I cannot download the workbook (no permission) to examine the code "in situ"

Comment: @nesrin from the little bit of code I can see, it appears you just deleted `#"Added Custom1"` instead of editing the formula.

Comment: I saw the formula you edited above and try that, it worked in the file i send to you. I am trying to use the same in the original data but since it has 6800 or more data, its been more than 20 min and still haven't completed. Is it posibble to do it in macro?

Comment: @nesrin it should not take that long for only 6,800 rows. And yes, it is possible to do it in macro. But I suspect there is something else about your data or the way you are using power query.

Comment: I don’t why but it seriously took 52 min to create table on advance editor and now waiting for load to excel spreadsheet. If you can help me about macro it will be super helpful

Comment: I try to use power query and record macro since i need this to be macro but i keep getting errors

Comment: @nesrin If it took that long, there are things I don't understand about your data. I would expect it to run in just a few seconds. If you want to write a macro, I suggest you read about using Class objects and Dictionaries, as well as working in VBA using arrays, rather than continually referencing the worksheet. Plenty of good info at the late Chip Pearson's webSite  (www.cpearson.com).

Comment: @nesrin OK, I figured out where the computation hangup is and I am trying to work around it.

Comment: @nesrin OK, see the last edit. Instead of using [Index] to refer to the previous/next row, I created offset columns and added them to the table. In testing on made up data of about 42,000 this routine took about 7 seconds to run.  I'll be interested to know if you see a significant improvement.

Comment: waoow it really shortened the time 7-10seconds.Congrats! I tried to record it as macro because i need it to be macro but when i run macro some problems occured. I had an error so it didnt work. Is not  PQ not suitable for using macro

Comment: @nesrin PQ can be used with VBA macros.

Comment: it gives an error as one of the columns name are not found but same column name is the same as PQ

Comment: @nesrin Consider that your problem lies elsewhere. By the way, my response seems to have answered the question you posed initally. If you agree, kindly mark it as Accepted. Perhaps you should consider creating a new question for your VBA Macro problem. Include details of what you have done, what you have for data input, what you want for output, and what you are getting from your macro.

Comment: i need it to be in macro as i mentioned earlier. I wrote a macro for this problem , see my edit on question. Could you help me fix the problem? for this row: dates = Cells(i, 1).Value it gives an error and says object vairable or with block are not set

Comment: @nesrin As I wrote previously, you should post this as a new question. Changing your original question to ask a new one is not appropriate for this forum. Please include what I mentioned in my last comment in your new question.

Answer (score 2):

One possible way is to use MAXIFS and MINIFS formula to get this result:

[image]

It can probably be done better, but if you select A:H and remove duplicates and uncheck column A then you get the result you are looking for I believe.

This assumes the date in column A is a true date and not just a text. If it's not a date then you will need to make it a date.
This can be done using DATEVALUE and RIGHT, LEFT, MID to make the string an accepted date format.

Then in E column you add this formula

```
=TEXT(A2,"YYYY-MM-DD")
```

In F:

```
=MAXIFS(A:A,E:E,TEXT(A2,"YYYY-MM-DD"),B:B,B2)
```

In G:

```
=MINIFS(A:A,E:E,TEXT(A2,"YYYY-MM-DD"),B:B,B2)
```

And lastly in H:

```
=F2-G2
```

When all formulas are on the sheet, select everything and copy, paste as values, then use remove duplicates like this:
[image]

and the result is this:

[image]

EDIT:
For completeness, this is how you convert your date to an accepted date format.

In M2 (example):

```
=MID(A2,7,4)&"-"&MID(A2,4,2)&"-"&LEFT(A2,2)&" "&RIGHT(A2,8)
```

then we need to use DATEVALUE and TIMEVALUE on this cell
N2:

```
=DATEVALUE(M2)+TIMEVALUE(M2)
```

Comment: I'd add a `COUNT.IF` to only output the results when you are in the first row of each day and worker.

Comment: Also possible. But I believe this will only be used once then more or less discarded. In those cases I don't put too much effort in to the formulas.

Comment: Thank you so much for your concern. Do you guys know how to do it in macro? Because there are other steps that should do in macro, i need this to be done by macro

Comment: Hi again, i need some modifications on that solution, i need to do the same thing but i should consider all date times not just max and min. How should i edit? I should find the total hours stayed on that day and i need to calculate all of entry and exist hours